# how to get volume data using ssh connection

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm trying to pull docker volume data from the remote server. Now my docker volume data is on my local machine. But I want to make this data available to everyone. So I copied docker volume file to the server. How do I show the file path of my docker volume data on this server in the compose file? Like;

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  jira:
    container_name: jira-software_8.3
    image: atlassian/jira-software:8.3

    volumes:
      # How to get volume data using ssh connection
      - <user_name>@<server_ip>:<server_path>:<container_path>

    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      - 'JIRA_DATABASE_URL=postgresql://jira@postgresql/jira_db'
      - 'JIRA_DB_PASSWORD=docker'

volumes:
  jira_data:
    external: false
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: How to add remote server file path to volume file path used in docker compose? @LinPy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not mount remote server files and folders, docker looking for mounting in the local context.

So the work arround is to copy during run time and mount the directory to a container.

```
scp -r -i yourkey.pem  centos@host.example.com:/home/centos/backup ./app/ && docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/app:/app alpine ash -c "ls /app"
```

your current docker-compose

```
    volumes:
      # How to get volume data using ssh connection
```

as you can not bind `- <user_name>@<server_ip>:<server_path>:<container_path>`

```
scp -r -i yourkey.pem  centos@host.example.com:/home/centos/backup ./app/ && docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/app:/app alpine ash -c "ls /app"
```

below will break your docker-compose

```
    volumes:
      # How to get volume data using ssh connection
      - <user_name>@<server_ip>:<server_path>:<container_path>
```

update the docker-compose file

```
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app/
```

then run docker-compose up command like

```
scp -r -i yourkey.pem  centos@host.example.com:/home/centos/backup ./app/ && docker-compose up
```